# Bootstrap in Yii2 framework works in local machine but not in Windows server IIS

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, iis, yii2, iis-10

I'm developing a web site with the Yii2 framework.

I Have a problem with bootstrap3. When I launch the code in my local machine with XAMPP it works correctly and bootstrap works, but when I deploy the code in the server working with windows server 2019 and IIS 10.0.1, bootstrap doesn't work. Any idea to fix the bug? thanks :)

Comment: Please provide some details because this question is too broad

Comment: What error message did you get? Did you get 404 in web browser developer tool->network tab? Did you get error message in developer tool->console tab? Bootstrap is just static file framework and it shouldn't be a problem in IIS. Besides, have you installed Static content in IIS?

Comment: i don't get error messages neither in browser nor in console. Should i installed other tools in server ? I installed git for the code and composer for the dependencies. (It's my first time with Yii2)